# In Terraform, how do I run a specific *.tf file in a directory?

Tags: terraform, devops, open-source, infrastructure-as-code, hashicorp

Using Terraform 0.12.6

I have a directory with multiple `*.tf` files, e.g., `product1.tf`, `product2.tf` etc. How can I execute `terraform plan` and subsequently `terraform apply` for a certain *.tf file? I was hoping it would be the `-target` option but I read the docs and didn't see this mentioned.

Comment: You can't. Terraform concatenates all the `.tf` files in a directory and works on them all at once. You can use `-target` to target specific resources but it has no idea what file they're all in. `-target` in general should be used sparingly as an escape hatch, if you need to run separate bits of Terraform at a time then split your Terraform code up into separate directories and state files.

Comment: yes that makes sense now thanks. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it as such if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Terraform concatenates all the `.tf` files in a directory and works on them all at once.

You can use [`-target`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#target-resource) to target specific resources but it has no idea what file they're all in.

`-target` in general should be used sparingly as an escape hatch, if you need to run separate bits of Terraform at a time then split your Terraform code up into separate directories and state files.

This is also discussed in [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting):

> This targeting capability is provided for exceptional circumstances,
>   such as recovering from mistakes or working around Terraform
>   limitations. It is not recommended to use `-target` for routine
>   operations, since this can lead to undetected configuration drift and
>   confusion about how the true state of resources relates to
>   configuration.
>
> Instead of using `-target` as a means to operate on isolated portions of
>   very large configurations, prefer instead to break large
>   configurations into several smaller configurations that can each be
>   independently applied. Data sources can be used to access information
>   about resources created in other configurations, allowing a complex
>   system architecture to be broken down into more manageable parts that
>   can be updated independently.